# Question about integrability of some functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a question to ask please.

$f=x\sin(1/x)$ ($f(0)=0$);

$f=\sin x/x$    ($f(0)=0$);

$f=(1/x)\cos(1/x^2)$ ($f(0)=0$);

$x\in [0,1]$ for all the cases.

Are those functions integrable? That means that also they have a derivative?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check Lebesgue criteria for Riemann integrability. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243560/riemann-integrable-function).

Comment: No, a function does not need to be continuous to be integrable, and yet differentiable functions are continuous. I suspect you may have instead wanted to ask whether functions that are integrable are necessarily *derivatives*. The answer is no anyway. One could also ask whether derivatives are necessarily integrable, and again the answer is no, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/705428/462).

Comment: Thanks for the responses but are those functions in my first post integrable?Do the have a derivative?

Comment: For the specific functions you mention, review the limit definition of derivative, and see whether one can compute the relevant limits.

Comment: Just because a function is integrable, doesn't mean it's also differentiable (has a derivative).